# Angular Material Table, use directive *ngIf; else inside a table

Tags: angular, directive

I work with angular material to display some data in my component.
I a display a table with some informations. But for the display a image, I have to use the directive *ngIf because some items have an image an another have not.

For the item who have an image (item.poster_path === true), the image display is that:
...img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w200/{{element.poster_path}}"...>

And for the item which have not image (item.poster_path === false), i want to display this image:
...img src="../../assets/not_found.jpg" alt="...">

This is the template of my page:

```html
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  
      <ng-container matColumnDef="poster">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Poster</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w200/{{element.poster_path}}" alt="..."> </td>
      </ng-container>
  
      <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Title </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.title}} </td>
      </ng-container>
  
      <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Release date </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.release_date | date: 'dd MMMM, y'}} </td>
      </ng-container>

  
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
  
    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
  </div>
```

And this is an exemple of a component that i use who show the directive with the image displayed:

```html
<div class="list" *ngIf="movie">
    <div class="list-img" *ngIf="movie.poster_path; else notFound">
        <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w200/{{movie.poster_path}}" alt="...">

    </div>
    <ng-template #notFound>
        <div class="list-img">
            <img src="../../assets/not_found.jpg" alt="...">
        </div>
```

If you can help me, I'll be very happy !

Thanks

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I don't know how add the directive *ngIf in the table